# Getting the Actual Error Source in Go with Uber/Zap Logging in gRPC Middleware

Tags: go

I am using the uber/zap package for logging.
In my design, I log any errors in the middleware of the grpc package.
I want to record which file and line number the error comes from.
However, currently, I can only get the filename and line number of the current middleware.
Is there any way to get the actual source of the error?

```golang
func RegisterLogger(c config.Config) *zap.SugaredLogger {

    var logger *zap.Logger
    var err error
    if c.IsDebug {
        logger, err = zap.NewDevelopment()
    } else {
        logger, err = zap.NewProduction()
    }

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer logger.Sync()

    return logger.Sugar()
}



func (s *ProviderServer) Pay(ctx context.Context, in *payment.PayRequest) (string, error) {
    resp, err := ctx.Value(in.Provider).(provider.IPayment).Exec(ctx, in)

    if err != nil {
            pc, file, line, ok := runtime.Caller(2)
            if ok {
                file = filepath.Base(file)
                nowTime := time.Now().Format("2006/01/02 15:04:05")
                funcName := runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name()
                funcName = filepath.Ext(funcName)
                funcName = strings.TrimPrefix(funcName, ".")
                s.log.Info("Times:", i, " nowTime:", nowTime, " file:", file, " line:", line, " funcName:", funcName, " err:", err)
            }
        
//Log the error information, including which file the error comes from.

        return resp.Result, err
    } else {
        s.log.Info("resp:", resp)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current implementation, you are trying to log the file and line number where an error occurs. However, the information you are getting is for the current middleware, not the actual source of the error.

To get the file and line information of the actual source of the error, you can make use of the `pkg/errors` package. This package provides a way to wrap errors and preserve the file and line information. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

// ...

func (s *ProviderServer) Pay(ctx context.Context, in *payment.PayRequest) (string, error) {
    resp, err := ctx.Value(in.Provider).(provider.IPayment).Exec(ctx, in)

    if err != nil {
        // Wrap the error with file and line information
        err = errors.Wrap(err, "pay error")

        // Log the wrapped error
        s.log.Errorw("Error occurred", "error", err)

        return resp.Result, err
    } else {
        s.log.Infow("Request processed successfully", "response", resp)
        return resp.Result, nil
    }
}
```

By wrapping the error with the `errors.Wrap` function, you add the file and line information to the error. Then, when logging the error using `s.log.Errorw`, the log message will contain the complete stack trace including the file and line information where the error originated.

This way, you can trace the actual source of the error using the information provided by the `errors` package.